# Angular 6: make 2 api calls for every element of the array

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

In my Angular6 app, I have an effect which first gets user ids and then makes 2 API calls for every id: getName and getAge. Ideally, I would like the data to be received grouped by ids: first data for the first id, then for the second and so on. Example: [ [Anna, 18], [Max, 22] ].

How to achieve that? I thought that zip operator can help, but can't figure out the correct way. With this code below, API calls don't happen, although a breakpoint hits both functions that make the calls.

```
@Effect()
loadAllNames$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType(allUsersActions.LOAD_ALL_NAMES)
    .pipe(
        concatMap(action => {
            return this.apiService.getUserIds()
        }),
        switchMap(ids => {  // [ 3423, 1222, 43234, 1232];
            let observableBatch = ids.map(id => {
              this.apiService.getName(id),  // brekpoint hits this fn
              this.apiService.getAge(id) // brekpoint hits this fn
            })
            return zip(observableBatch)
            .pipe(
                switchMap((res) => {
                    this.store.dispatch(new allUsersActions.SetAllUsers(res));
                    return of(
                        new spinnerActions.HideSpinner()
                    )
                }),
                catchError(error => of(new spinnerActions.HideSpinner()))
          )
        })
    )
```

API service:

```
  public getName(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(URL + id)
  }
```

Comment: What is content of console.log(observableBatch)? Do you have this.apiService.getAge also defined next to getName in your service, right?

Comment: @Adam , i don't know why but console.log(observableBatch) returns an array of `undefined`. However, functions in api service gets the correct ids. And yes, `getAge()` also exists in the service.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the inner `switchMap` that will take one `id` after another and run both calls at once.

```
...
switchMap(ids => from(ids).pipe(
  concatMap(id => forkJoin(
    this.apiService.getName(id),
    this.apiService.getAge(id),
  )),
  toArray(),
)),
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-85y3bv

Comment: these requests will be consequentual with such implementation. it is better to make them parallel

Comment: @Andrei what do you mean by 'these requests will be consequential'? And what's the correct way on your opinion? Thanks

Comment: `concatMap` causes your requests to be sent one after another, not in parallel. I'd say the correct way would be `of(ids).pipe(switchMap((ids) => forkJoin(ids.map(id => forkJoin(this.apiService.getName(id),this.apiService.getAge(id))))))`